# Laravel Where is getting ignored

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My laravel "where" is getting ignored it seems. **->where('products.hide_product', '=', 'N')**
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
  $products = Product::join('brands','products.brand_id','=','brands.brand_id')
                            ->join('categories','products.cat_id','=','categories.cat_id')
                            ->leftJoin('images','products.product_id','=','images.product_id')->where('img_priority','=','1')->orWhere('img_priority', '=', null)
                            ->where('products.hide_product', '=', 'N')->where('products.group_id', '=', $groupID)->orderBy('img_priority','DESC')
                            ->get(array('products.en_71','products.astm','images.file_name','products.product_id','products.product_name','products.collect_part_no','brands.brand_name','categories.cat_name','products.status','images.file_type','products.pop','products.color_label','products.ai_complete'));
```

Comment: If you set up your models and their relationships correctly, this would be more easily done in Eloquent. As it is, there isn't enough information to help. A good start would be formatting your code to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the join in a closure an use the first `where` there:

```
$products = Product::join('brands', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.brand_id')
    ->join('categories','products.cat_id','=','categories.cat_id')
    ->leftJoin('images', function ($join) {
        $join->on('products.product_id','=','images.product_id')
        ->where('img_priority','=','1')
        ->orWhere('img_priority', '=', null);
    })
    ->where(
        ['products.hide_product', '=', 'N'],
        ['products.group_id', '=', $groupID],
    )
     ->select('products.en_71', 'products.astm', 'images.file_name', 'products.product_id', 'products.product_name', 'products.collect_part_no', 'brands.brand_name', 'categories.cat_name', 'products.status', 'images.file_type',  'images.img_priority', 'products.pop', 'products.color_label', 'products.ai_complete')
    ->orderBy('img_priority', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
$products = Product::join('brands','products.brand_id','=','brands.brand_id')
    ->join('categories','products.cat_id','=','categories.cat_id')
    ->leftJoin('images', function($join)) {
        $join->on('products.product_id','=','images.product_id')
             ->where(function($query){
                $query->where('img_priority','=','1')
                      ->orWhere('img_priority', '=', null)
            })
        }
        ->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('products.hide_product', '=', 'N')
                  ->where('products.group_id', '=', $groupID)
        })
        ->orderBy('img_priority','DESC')
        ->get(array('products.en_71','products.astm','images.file_name',
                    'products.product_id','products.product_name',
                    'products.collect_part_no', 'brands.brand_name',
                    'categories.cat_name', 'products.status',
                    'images.file_type','products.pop','products.color_label',
                    'products.ai_complete')
             );
```